# Web-based XML to Text File

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that lives on an internal IP address and is regularly updated:

```
<DATA>
<HEADLINE>
<TEXT>Headline 1</TEXT>
</HEADLINE>
<HEADLINE>
<TEXT>Headline 2</TEXT>
</HEADLINE>
<HEADLINE>
<TEXT>Headline 3</TEXT>
</HEADLINE>
</DATA>
```

etc for anywhere from 5-15 headlines. I would like to spit this out to a .txt file formatted

```
Headline 1
Headline 2
Headline 3
```

etc.

It seems like XSLT would work, but I'm having difficulty telling a script to pull it from the web address (which is static: http://10.2.1.11/cgi-bin/ExportHeadlines.pl). Is there a better way to create this .txt file?

Comment: Well, we don't know what "I'm having difficulty telling a script to pull it from the web address" means and whether we can fix it if you don't show any details. Which XSLT processor, which script language do you use to run the XSLT, how does your code look, which error exactly do you get?

Comment: I can't figure out how to specify a URL as the xml source to export as a file.

Comment: As I said, spell out some details, you managed to put a URL into your question, it is not clear where you can't use it with XSLT, but you have not given any indication about the context in which you try to run XSLT, try "telling a script ..", it is better to use the relevant tags and show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

For the **`.txt` file output** you can [specify the target format](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_output.asp) in your XSL stylesheet

```
<xsl:output method="text" media-type="text/plain" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
```

To **load the XML document over HTTP** you can use the [`document` function](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_document.asp)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="document('http://10.2.1.11/cgi-bin/ExportHeadlines.pl')/DATA"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Since the source file is regularly updated, you need some kind of **scheduler that executes the XSL transformation on a regular base**.

Probably you also must provide an input XML file (that you don't use because you load your data inside the XSL stylesheet). Just **use a pseudo file** to make it happy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test/>
```

#### Alternative: Download first

You can of course also **pull the XML data with curl** or a similar tool in a first step and then do a **plain vanilla XSL transformation with the downloaded XML data file**.